# How to have different actions based on previous action's sender in objC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, delegates, selector

```
- (IBAction)popUpAreYouSureView:(id)sender {
    self.areYouSureView.hidden = NO;
}

- (IBAction)pressedYes {
    // if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was switch, do something

    // else if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was close, do something else
} 

- (IBAction)pressedNo {
    // if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was switch, do something

    // else if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was close, do something else
}
```

Suppose I have 2 buttons "switch" and "close", both connected to popUpAreYouSureView, which unhides a view named areYouSureView when tapped. The "are you sure?" view has 2 buttons: "yes" and "no", connected to pressdYes and pressedNo respectively.

When I press "yes" or "no", then I will check whether the "switch" or "close" button had unhid my view. Depending on which button unhid my view, I want to perform different logic. The problem I am running into is how do I know whether the "switch" or "close" button unhid my view without storing that information.

What is a clean way to do this? I looked into delegates but this doesn't seem to work because I am passing the same delegate for both the switch and close case. Same problem with selectors. Do I have to store the (id)sender that tells me if the previous action came from the switch or close button, so that the action connected to the "yes" or "no" button can look it up and figure out what logic to do?

Comment: what type is `self.areYouSureView`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of what caused the action, there's no way around this really. As such, make good use of the `sender` parameter.

```
__weak UIButton* m_buttonSelected;

- (IBAction)popUpAreYouSureView:(id)sender {
    self.areYouSureView.hidden = NO;
    m_buttonSelected = (UIButton*)sender;
}

- (IBAction)pressedYes {
    // if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was switch, do something
    if ([m_buttonSelected isEqual:self.switchButton]) {
        ...
    }
    // else if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was close, do something else
    else if ([m_buttonSelected isEqual:self.closeButton]) {
        ...
    }

    m_buttonSelected = nil;
} 

- (IBAction)pressedNo {
    // if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was switch, do something
    if ([m_buttonSelected isEqual:self.switchButton]) {
        ...
    }
    // else if sender from popUpAreYouSureView was close, do something else
    else if ([m_buttonSelected isEqual:self.closeButton]) {
        ...
    }

    m_buttonSelected = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast (but not so pretty) solution would be to use the "tag" property of the areYouSureView view.
Give each of the buttons a different tag (1 for close and 2 for switch, for example) and then you can do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)popUpAreYouSureView:(id)sender {
    self.areYouSureView.hidden = NO;
    self.areYouSureView.tag = ((UIView*)sender).tag; 
}

- (IBAction)pressedYes {
    if (self.areYouSureView.tag == 1)
        NSLog(@"Button 1");
    else
        NSLog(@"Button 2");
} 

- (IBAction)pressedNo {
    if (self.areYouSureView.tag == 1)
        NSLog(@"Button 1");
    else
        NSLog(@"Button 2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is redefining your buttons actions in `popUpAreYouSureView`:

```
- (IBAction)popUpAreYouSureView:(id)sender {

  if ([sender...]) {
    [self.yesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(...) forControlEvents:...];
    [self.yesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(...) forControlEvents:...];
  } else {
    [self.yesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(...) forControlEvents:...];
    [self.yesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(...) forControlEvents:...];
  }
}
```

An slightly better solution would be using a delegate in `pressedYes` and `pressedNo` implementation taking care of setting the delegate in `popUpAreYouSureView`:

```
- (IBAction)popUpAreYouSureView:(id)sender {

  if ([sender...]) 
     self.buttonsDelegate = ...;
  else
     self.buttonsDelegate = ...;
}



- (IBAction)pressedYes {
    [self.delegate doYes];
} 

- (IBAction)pressedNo {
    [self.delegate doNo];
}
```

Both methods should work.